# Website error only on certain iPhone 5 and 6

Tags: ios, css, iphone, mobile, safari

The site loads off center on iPhone 6 and the backgrounds is not 100% width on iPhone 5. I've checked multiple 5 & 6 phones, every browser, and simulator and I DO NOT SEE THE ERROR. The client says it looks this way on their phone using safari running IOS v9.21. I even went out and bought an iPhone 6. It looks completely fine. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Please help.

[Link to site](http://www.devildemonsystems.com/)

[iPhone 6s+ ios v9.21 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT9OA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys are looking at 2 different URLs ?

http://silverdraft.com/
http://www.devildemonsystems.com/

Screenshot has a url like silverdraft.com, which loads your URL in a frameset.

Comment: WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY THIS??? and please put these lines as comment.. For god sake don't post these lines in answer section.

Comment: What the hell. OK so they are loading the site into an iframe on another url that I don't have access to. The did no tell me this at all. THANK YOU!